# Automatic page break for mdframed near bottom

Tags: environments, page-breaking, theorems, mdframed

I've been trying to define my own theorem environment using `mdframed` package. I'm now encountering a problem with page breaks -- if I start a theorem environment near the bottom of a page, sometimes the page break becomes very awkward as only theorem name gets displayed on the previous page and everything else gets pushed back to the second page. [image: Here is one example, and the MWE below should be able to reproduce it.]

MWE that includes one good example and one bad exmaple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm}

\newenvironment{issue}[1][]{%

    \mdfsetup{%
            frametitle={%
                \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
                \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=cyan!20]
                {\strut ~#1};}}%
    \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=cyan!40,%
        linewidth=2pt,topline=true
    }
    \begin{mdframed}[]\hspace{16pt}\relax%
        \label{#1}}{\end{mdframed}}
    
\begin{document}
    \par This is working fine.
    \begin{issue}[This is working fine]
        There is no awkward page break here.
    \end{issue}
    \vspace{19cm} 
    \par Below is the issue.
    \begin{issue}[Having Issue with Page Break]
        This is on the second page. \lipsum[2]
    \end{issue}
\end{document}
```

All I want is to make sure that the previous page displays at least 2 or 3 lines, say. Then things would look better. If there's not enough space for two lines then I'd like to push everything to the second page.
Is there a certain way to make this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: If possible use tcolorbox instead of mdframed. It is much better with breakable boxes.  Beside this you can try the needspace package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the advice. I'll look into it.